# How to save files in CSV via Python maintaining the decimal separator in the same place? (And differences in Excel and Google Sheets)

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, csv, google-sheets

I have a script that makes a request via API and saves the data in a CSV file. The data is stored in different lists in python and must be in different columns in the CSV. The data from these lists are unicode (and I tried to convert them to string and float before convert to .csv but didn't work) If I print the results, this will appear on the screen (which are the correct values):

```
01/02/2019 01:00:00 -  568.5200 -  608.7472 -  654.1030
```

If I open the .csv file with Excel, the values have the decimal separator placed in wrong places. Like this:

```
01/02/2019 01:00    5.685.200   6.087.472   6.541.030
```

If I open the .csv file with Google Sheets the values ​​are not separated in columns, but are correct. Like this:

```
01/02/2019 01:00:00;568.5200;608.7472;654.1030
```

I'm using `izip` and `writer.writerows` to convert the lists to .csv in different columns:

```
import csv
from itertools import izip

#A lot of code

with open('Latency.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter = ';')
    writer.writerows(izip(dates, values_min, values_avg, values_max))
```

Comment: you should check with a text editor if the file look right /eg Notepad++ or Sublime) 
If the data is ok - only after that - you can and should open the file in Excel BUT not via double-clicking but via the Open-File Menu and then choose .csv file as source which should lead you through the Text import wizard where you can then adjust the parameters accordingly to get a clean import into Excel

Comment: I did this. The data looks fine (`01/02/2019 01:00:00;568.5200;608.7472;654.1030`). For me it is not viable to use the Text import wizard because I'm trying to automate the whole process. Any ideias why Google Sheets doesn't separate the data into columns?

Comment: It's an Excel thing (Google does much less guessing of formats when opening a file compared to Excel) …. if you wanna automate I guess hacking the process (i.e. replacing getting rid of various seperators in the file data) with e.g. vb-script could be an option (vbs if you are on windows); ps: seems like Excel does not like your decimal separators in the file. copy the file (for Excel use) and replace the "." (dots) with "," (Commas) I guess (if you are on European formats); if the dots are your Thsd separator get rid of it

Comment: I replaced '.' with ',' in my Python lists and everything went fine. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just replaced the `'.'` with `','`:

```
def format(numbers):
    for number in numbers:
         yield str(number).replace(".", ",")

with open('Latency.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter = ';')
    writer.writerows(izip(datas, format(values_min), format(values_avg), format(values_max)))
```